# Вывод всех файлов в каталоге, задаваемом как параметр командной строки. (shell)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, foreach

Требуется сделать простенький скрипт, выводящий на экран название файла и затем его содержимое в задаваемом каталоге. Попробовал модифицировать пример из методички:

```
cd $1
for f in *.txt
do
cat ${f}
done
```

Однако при запуске возникает ошибка

```
xred@xred-W65-67SJ:~$ ./7.sh /home/
cat: '*.txt': No such file or directory
```

Что я делаю не так?
В домашнем каталоге гарантированно находится несколько файлов с данным расширением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Xred "Что я делаю не так?"

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
path_to_dir="$1"

ls -R "${path_to_dir}"/*.txt \
| while read -r txt_file; do
  echo "$txt_file"
  cat "$txt_file"
 done
# End of script
```

В текущем каталоге, достаточно глобального значения пути:

```
~$ cat ./*.txt
```

Рекурсивно достаточно одного  find или grep:

```
~$ find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print -exec cat {} \;
~$ grep -r ".*" ./**/*.txt
```

Проверял с использованием:

- GNU coreutils
- GNU findutils
- GNU grep

Comment: А куда сюда прикрутить $1, чтобы передавать путь как аргумент командной строки?

Comment: Поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
find PATH_DIR -type f | while read FN; do echo $FN; cat $FN; done;
```

Comment: или `find PATH_DIR -type f -exec echo {} ";" -exec cat {} ";"`

Answer (score 0):

1. в каталоге `/home` обычно нет ни одного файла. поэтому ничего и не находится. вероятно, вы хотели указать домашний каталог какого-нибудь пользователя. по умолчанию это каталог `/home/имя_пользователя`.
2. для того, чтобы не получать сообщение об ошибке в случае, если файлов, подпадающих под маску, действительно нет, помимо предложенных в других ответах решений, можно установить в начале скрипта [опцию `nullglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

   ```
   shopt -s nullglob
   ```

   смысл её в том, что если под указанную маску (например, `*.txt`) не подпадает ни одного объекта файловой системы (т.е., нет ни файлов, ни каталогов, ни символических ссылок, имена которых заканчиваются символами `.txt`), то результатом подстановки будет не *сама маска* — `*.txt` (так происходит по умолчанию), а пустая строка.

   но будьте осторожны. например, если в каталоге нет ни одного файла, подпадающего под маску, то команда вида `ls *.txt` вернёт **всё** содержимое каталога, как будто программа `ls` была вызвана вообще без параметра. а вот команда `for f in *.txt; do тело-цикла; done` отработает так, как и ожидается — тело цикла не будет выполнено ни разу.